# 500 Internal Server Error fetch()'ing data with Next.js app deployed on Netlify (works locally)

Tags: next.js, fetch, netlify

I'm building a toy app with Next.js 13 (with the new `app/` directory). My app works fine locally, but generates a 500 Internal Server Error when deployed to Netlify.

Here's the route that generates the error

**`app/team/[id]/page.jsx`**

```
import Link from "next/link";

async function getEmployee() {

    const res = await fetch(
        'https://dynamic-routes--dundermifflininc.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/team?id=1',
        { cache: 'no-store' }
    );

    return await res.json();
}

export default async function Employee() {

    const employee = await getEmployee();

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{ employee.name }</h1>
            <h3>{ employee.title }</h3>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I am confident that the error is happening with `fetch()`, because if I replace `fetch()` with hard-coded data, the app works properly. Additionally, the logs for my netlify function indicate that the endpoint isn't even being hit by the `fetch()` call.

The Netlify function is defined like this

**`netlify/functions/team.js`**

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {

  const employees = [
    { id: 1, name: "Michael Scott", title: "Regional manager" },
    { id: 2, name: "Jim Halpert", title: "Salesman" },
    { id: 3, name: "Pam Beesly", title: "Receptionist" },
    { id: 4, name: "Dwight Schrute", title: "Assistant to the regional manager" },
  ];

  var data;
  if (event.queryStringParameters.hasOwnProperty("id")) {
    const id = parseInt(event.queryStringParameters.id);
    data = employees[id - 1];
  } else {
    data = employees;
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
  };
};
```

You can test the endpoint for yourself [here](https://dynamic-routes--dundermifflininc.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/team?id=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce this on a demo site, but checking the logs for your example it's giving the error: "Error: Page changed from static to dynamic at runtime /team/1, see more here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/app-static-to-dynamic-error
I'm not sure why it's trying to statically render it when you have no-store set, but you might want to try following the instruction in the linked doc, and exporting `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'` in the page.
A good way to track this down is to run `netlify serve` locally, using the latest version of the Netlify CLI. This is a new option that runs the site in a production-like environment